# Bitrise Update JIRA issues with build number not working

Tags: android, jira, bitrise

```
    + DEB_FILES=("${THIS_SCRIPT_DIR}/ubuntu/products/"*.deb)
    + dpkg -i /tmp/bitrise032434122/step_src/ubuntu/products/libgit2_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
    Selecting previously unselected package libgit2.
    (Reading database ... 87887 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../libgit2_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libgit2 (1.1.0) ...
    Setting up libgit2 (1.1.0) ...
    ++ mktemp -d
    + TMP_GOPATH_DIR=/tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ
    + GO_PACKAGE_NAME=github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build
    + FULL_PACKAGE_PATH=/tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ/src/github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build
    + mkdir -p /tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ/src/github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build
    + rsync -avh --quiet /tmp/bitrise032434122/step_src/ /tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ/src/github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build/
    + export GOPATH=/tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ
    + GOPATH=/tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ
    + go run /tmp/tmp.42ieHQKVTQ/src/github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build/main.go
    # github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build/vendor/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v30
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.0.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `ERR_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `ERR_lib_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `sk_num@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
...
...
...
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgit2.so: undefined reference to `EVP_md5@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    WARN[09:07:09] Step (jira-issue-update-build@0) failed, but was marked as skippable 
    |                                                                              |
    +---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
    | ! | jira-issue-update-build@0 (exit code: 2)                      | 28.28 sec|
    +---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
    | Issue tracker: https://github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build/issues     |
    | Source: https://github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build                   |
    +---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

I want to set build number to JIRA issues in Bitrise, I tried 'Update JIRA issues with build number' workflow in Bitrise, but it doesn't work.

I can't find any information about this error.....

How to fix it?

Comment: This seems like a bug/issue in that specific step. The step isn't developed and maintained by bitrise, it's a community developed and maintained step, so the best is to report the issue on the step's issue tracker -> you can see it in the log: Issue tracker: https://github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build/issues

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in the step library, I've issued a fix in https://github.com/Holdapp/bitrise-step-jira-build/pull/12 and it should be fixed in version `0.2.5`